# Navigating to a page causes the app to gets stuck in the current page and exits debug mode automatically

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working on the Xamarin iOS application and navigating to the login page that is when my app gets stuck in the current page ie the page where i am navigating from.

The debug point don't come to Initialise component of Login page nor it gets logged in catch the app gets stuck for a while and exits debug mode without any errors or exception

This navigation is basic, other pages are being navigated only issue is with the login page.

Also please let me know what parts of code should i Share

Please let me know if there is any solution.

Comment: Hi  Gautham, can you share how you navigate from login to the next page?

Comment: Probably there is some problem with the login page's xaml. Try commenting out most of it, see if you can get page to load.

Comment: Please help create a [Minimal,Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I created a new page and copied all the contents of Login page to new xaml and xaml.cs File and it worked. I think the Login page was corrupted. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

I made a new page and copied all the contents of Login page to the new page and it worked, the underlying issue was the Login Page was corrupted when transferring from Windows To Mac,

As per why i think it was corrupted, because the debug point at Initialize component and onAppearing didn't work at all